# Can I show and hide element using :focus

Tags: html, css

I would like to show/hide some container by clicking on button using CSS.  Now, I have something like below which allows me to show container but how to hide it by clicking on the same button?

```
.button {
        &:focus {
            & + .menu-list {
                display: block;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: If you want a "toggle" functionality, you must use javascript...

Comment: Use a checkbox and label instead, and the :checked pseudo class.

Comment: Use `.toggleClass()`

Comment: @FlorinPop but when I use JS I will not able to hide menu when I click outside the menu. I would had to click on menu button every time

Comment: You can
1. find out if the button is focused and unfocus it on the 2nd click.. or
2. check in javascript if the click is outside the menu (which is a little harder I think)

Answer (score 1):

## Toggle using CSS only (with a checkbox)

This is a little update. As CBroe stated in the comments, you can achieve this with a checkbox and CSS:

```css
#toggle-button,
.menu-list {
  display: none;
}

#toggle-button:checked + .menu-list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle-button">open/close</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-button" />

<div class="menu-list">Hello world</div>
```

Use a checkbox and label instead, and the :checked pseudo class. – CBroe 7

The original post below:

---

## Vanilla JavaScript toggle method

As many mentioned in the comments, use a toggle method. The easiest - as far as I know - is to use `HTMLElement#classList.toggle`:

```js
const menuList = document.querySelector( '.menu-list' );
document.querySelector( '.toggle-button' ).addEventListener( 'click', () => {
  menuList.classList.toggle( '-visible' );
} );
```

```css
.menu-list {
  display: none;
}

.menu-list.-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle-button">open/close</button>
<div class="menu-list">Hello world</div>
```

---

## Vanilla JavaScript toggle method with focus/blur

You also could go with your solution but somehow need to unfocus (`blur`) the button as needed, maybe something like this:

```js
const menuList = document.querySelector( '.menu-list' );
const button = document.querySelector( '.toggle-button' );
let isVisible = false;

button.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
  isVisible = !isVisible;
  if ( !isVisible ) {
    button.blur();
  }
} );
```

```css
.menu-list {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-button:focus + .menu-list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle-button">open/close</button>
<div class="menu-list">Hello world</div>
```

---

## jQuery toggle method

And of course there is an easy solution with `jQuery#toggleClass` as well and still more than valid when you are already using jQuery:

```js
const $menuList = $( '.menu-list' );
$( '.toggle-button' ).click( () => $menuList.toggleClass( '-visible' ) );
```

```css
.menu-list {
  display: none;
}

.menu-list.-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle-button">open/close</button>
<div class="menu-list">Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle functionality using jquery like this:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $("your container id").toggle();
});
```

It should toggle your container block.

Answer (score 0):

For a partial solution, you can take advantage of `:focus-within`.

You can open the menu on click of the button, and close it by clicking elsewhere - Unfortunately the button itself will not act as a toggle in this case.

Note that `:focus-within` does not have universal support. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```css
.menu-list {
  display: none;
}

.container:focus-within .menu-list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Open Menu</button>
  <div class="menu-list">Hello world</div>
</div>
```